# Connecting to tableau server from tableau desktop 10

Tags: tableau-api

I cannot connect from Tableau desktop 10 to Tableau server 10.
I can connect and publish from tableau desktop 9.3 but when I changed to tableau desktop 10 I am getting - "Socket operation timed out" & "Connection timed out" issues. This sounds weird but server connection is changed in tableau desktop 10. Did anyone else have this issue?

Comment: It's been working fine for me and my colleagues. When you say "I am getting issues", what types of issues?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Check whether all services are running using the tabadmin or web UI. If you have ports being blocked in firewall you can have the error. Check whether you are using the correct port when connecting to server from desktop.

Comment: Did you checked the logs? Here small instructions how to have clean logs folder and where to find them: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/sending-desktop-logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update the answer here, but this is what the issue!

> There was some change in handling redirects in Tableau 10, when you use some other
>   system to redirect connections, HTTP redirects were handling wrongly
>   from port 80. After fixing it in settings on the server and restarting the server
>   everything backs to normal.